# Unable to start redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to start a redmine on following configuration:

- OS: Mac OS X Snow Leopard with all updates.
- Ruby: 1.8.7
- Rails: 2.3.5
- Rack: 1.0.1

with following commands:

```
svn checkout redmine.rubyforge.org/svn/tags/1.0.2 redmine
cd redmine
cp config/database.yml.example config/database.yml
vi config/database.yml
Changed production and development to SQLite
rake generate_session_store
RAILS_ENV=development rake db:migrate
RAILS_ENV=development rake redmine:load_default_data
ruby script/server -e development
```

Server starts OK and shows redmine welcome page at http://0.0.0.0:3000,
but after logging in as admin/admin and clicking on the "profile" link,
i have:

```
ArgumentError in My#account
Showing app/views/my/_sidebar.rhtml where line #4 raised:
wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)

Extracted source (around line #4):
1: <%=l(:label_my_account)%>
2: 
3: <%=l(:field_login)%>: <%= @user.login %>
4: <%=l(:field_created_on)%>: <%= format_time(@user.created_on) %>
5: 
6: 
7: <%= l(:label_feeds_access_key) %>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/my/account.rhtml
RAILS_ROOT: /Users/eye/rails/redmine
```

Same error with `trunk` and with `production`. I can't understood the ruby error since in code it's a 2 arguments call for 2 parameters method but error states that method has 0 parameters. Any hints what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: post a bug report on redmine bugtracker.

Comment: Since it's a stable version not working for me it's a 95% chance that i'm doing something wrong: like having a wrong ruby/rails/whatsover version/configuration or missing some magic environment variable :). So i want to check this on stackoverflow/google/forums before posting bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling i18n ruby gem or downgrading it to 0.3.7 fixes a problem O_O.
Fixed in development version (and will be fixed in 1.0.4 stable).